# Calling _msize() via PInvoke from C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I'm writing a C# library where the calling app will pass in a large amount of contiguous, unmanaged memory. This calling app can be either from .Net or Visual C++ (it will go through an intermediate C++/CLI library before calling my library if from C++). It would be useful to validate that there is sufficient memory, so I decided to call the _msize() function.  Unfortunately, _msize always seems to give me the wrong size back.
I went back and modified my allocation routine in my sample app and then immediately call _msize. Here is my code snipet:

```
public unsafe class MyMemory
{
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int _msize(IntPtr handle);

    public static IntPtr MyAlloc(int size)
    {
        IntPtr retVal = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        ...

        int memSize = MyMemory._msize(retVal);
        if (memSize < size)
        {
        ...
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

When I pass in the size 199229440, I get back memSize of 199178885. I've seen similar results for different numbers. It is less than 0.01% off, which I would totally understand if it was over, but the fact is it is under, meaning _msize thinks the allocated memory is less than what was asked for.  Anyone have any clue why this is? And any recommendations on what I should do instead would be appreciated as well.

Comment: `_msize` returns a size_t, which is unsigned (it is typically mapped via `IntPtr`).  Not claiming this is your problem, but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: There are multiple heaps in a Windows program.  AllocHGlobal allocates from the *different* heap.  _msize can only give accurate info for memory allocated by malloc().  You can get what you want by pinvoking LocalSize (not GlobalSize as the name would suggest).  Forgetting the allocated size is rather odd, be sure to *not* assume that an IntPtr came from the right heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P/Invoke the `LocalSize` function instead.

`_msize` is for determining the size of a block allocated with `malloc` (and its friends). `AllocHGlobal` is a wrapper around `GlobalAlloc` or `LocalAlloc` (depending on what reference you believe; but I think the two are equivalent), and you want the `LocalSize` function to determine the size of the block that actually returned. So far as I can tell, `Marshal` doesn't contain a wrapper for `LocalSize`, but you can call it using P/Invoke.

So it seems like it's only by sheer good luck that `_msize` is returning anything useful for you at all. Perhaps `malloc` uses `GlobalAlloc` (or `LocalAlloc`), either always or just when asked for large blocks, and requests a bit of extra space for bookkeeping; in which case `_msize` would be trying to compensate for that.

Comment: LocalSize gives the right answer. Thanks for the explanation. Still curious why _msize was giving something close, I was able to get similar results for a number of different sizes...